# outlook 2010 autocomplete disabled

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete, email-client

Autocomplete for e-mail addresses is not working in my Outlook 2010. The Microsoft help for [turning on autocomplete](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2682333) does not include the scenario where it's disabled. 
[image]
I've tried toggling the other checkboxes that I can still use and Emptying the Auto-Complete list. But it doesn't help and there's no tooltip on why the checkbox is disabled.

Edit: I tried [these forum suggestions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-autocomplete-not-working/3a2e9a0f-0a39-4aaf-9bc7-a9f362307736), including making the registry entry with value 1.

Comment: Try running `scanpst.exe` as per [Outlook 2010 Autocomplete not working](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-autocomplete-not-working/3a2e9a0f-0a39-4aaf-9bc7-a9f362307736). Check out the other answers in that post as well.

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: @DavidPostill tried didn't work. Also those posts are about autocomplete not working, not about it being disabled completely.

Comment: @AxelKemper Yes I tried that, including the fixit file, noted it in the question.

Comment: @MrFox One of the posts said "If you want to turn off this feature within Registry, create a DWORD key called "ShowAutoSug" with value 0 in key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences`". Did you check if this keys exists?

Comment: That key is to turn it off. so I don't think creating it is going to help. If you are going to create it, then it should have the value `1`. I don't think a reboot would be required in any case (just a restart of outlook).